# Does Django Oscar provide features to connect your e-commerce website with other e-commerce websites?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have not integrated Oscar in my Django project and I am planning to build an eCommerce web site using [Oscar](http://oscarcommerce.com/). But we will be having a requirement at later stage to add connector between our website and other eCommerce giants like Alibaba, Amazon, eBay.

That means I need different website APIs to push one or more products (taken from Django Oscar products) on different sites and track/manage orders done by users on those sites directly on our platform.

Does someone have any knowledge regarding this?

I am doing a detailed R&D and would add answer to this question if I find something related.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with Oscar, however you will need to do a fair amount of custom development to get your desired API integrations working.

Oscar is composed of numerous self-contained apps which allow you to "fork" and subclass all of it's code. This allows you to mold the framework to fit your exact business needs.

It sounds like you would need to "fork" the `catalogue` app, add whatever custom models you might need and then add code to integrate with all your other APIs (like pushing all new products to another API). If you are wanting to keep track of orders from other e-commerce platforms, you would probably need to fork the `dashboard` app and make some custom code to call your other APIs and display that info.

Here's an explanation on how to fork an app in Oscar:
https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.4/topics/fork_app.html